# SQL Server : how to use SQL statements to get the desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can use cursors, but it's inefficient. Is there a better way to use SQL statements to get these results?

Table： A

```
A1    ID      A2
--------------------
aaa   A      8:30
bbb   A      9:30
ccc   A      10:00
```

Table： B

```
ID    ​B2
----------
A    8:30
A    9:00
A    9:10
A    9:30
A    9:50
A    10:01
A    12:00
```

Desired results：

```
ID    B2    ​    ​A1
---------------------
A    8:30    ​    ​aaa
A    9:00    ​    ​aaa
A    9:10    ​    ​aaa
A    9:30    ​    ​bbb
A    9:50    ​    ​bbb
A    10:00    ​    ​bbb
A    10:01       ccc    
A    12:00       ccc
```

Comment: What is the datatypes of the A2 and B2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although you do not have a method to achieve,

Because your explanation is not enough.you should explain why 9:30 is ​bbb and why 
10:00 is bbb

I tried using sql server 2012+

```
declare @t table(A1 varchar(50),ID varchar(50), A2 time)
insert into @t values 
('aaa','A','8:30')
,('bbb','A','9:30')
,('ccc','A','10:00')  

--select *,LEAD(A2,1)over(order by id ) A2_EndTime from @t

declare @t1 table(ID varchar(50), ​B2 time)
insert into @t1 values 
('A','8:30')
,('A','9:00')
,('A','9:10')
,('A','9:30')
,('A','9:50')
,('A','10:01')
,('A','12:00')

;With CTE as
(
 select *,LEAD(A2,1)over(order by id ) A2_EndTime from @t
)
--select * from cte
,CTE1 as
(select t1.ID,t1.B2
from @t1 t1
)
,CTE2 as
(
select * from @t c where not exists(select b2 from cte1 c1 where c1.b2=c.a2)
)
,cte3 as
(
select id,b2 from cte1
union all
select id,a2 from cte2

)

select t1.ID,t1.B2
 ,(select top 1 t.A1  from CTE t where ((t.A2_EndTime is null and t1.b2>=t.a2 ) 
or (t.A2_EndTime is not null and (t1.b2 >= t.a2 and t1.b2< t.A2_EndTime) )))
from cte3 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. . . . This requires combining the two tables to create both rows and columns.  A bit tricky.  The rows suggest `union`.  The columns suggest something else, such as a `join` or correlated subquery:

```
select ab.id, ab.b2,
       (select a.a1
        from a
        where a.a2 <= ab.b2
        order by a.a2 desc
        limit 1
       ) as a1
from ((select id, a2 as b2 from a) union
      (select id, b2 from b)
     ) ab;
```

Comment: Although you do not have a method to achieve, but you gave me a new way of thinking, I have achieved, thank you very much.